# FatalErrorException (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I find something error in in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 156), How to fix, thanks

```
    protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
{
    $config = config('session');

    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie(
            'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() + 60 * $config['lifetime'],
            $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false
        )
    );

    return $response;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have `{{ csrf_field() }}` beneath your `<form>`?

Comment: Wait, are you editing the Laravel core files?

Comment: `$response->headers` doesn't exist.

Comment: @DainisAbols, I think people simply show error location.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in some your middleware.

Middleware `handle` method must return `Response` object, but looks like some your middleware(s) return non-response object.

`VerifyCsrfToken` middleware by calling `addCookieToResponse` method pass `$next($request)` as argument. So, next middleware call return wrong result.

Please, check all your middlewares, and fix it.